# Cant download package xlsx or rjava R

Tags: java, r, package, xlsx, rjava

I am trying to download the `xlsx` package in R but get the following error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'xlsx':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Users/X/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/xlsx'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xlsx’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have also tried to download `rjava`, but get this error message:

```
ERROR*> JavaSoft\{JRE|JDK} can't open registry keys.
ERROR: cannot find Java Development Kit.
       Please set JAVA_HOME to specify its location manually
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rJava'
* removing 'C:/Users/X/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rJava'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/X/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rJava'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have reinstalled Java to my computer, with the same architecture s my computer and R (64-bit), which most of the help online says that I should try out. Have anyone experienced the same problem?

Comment: Looks to me like your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable may not be set

Comment: But I just tried this Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121')  and then try to install.packages("rjava"), but t´still diesnt work @JeroenSteenbeeke

Comment: I'm not familiar with R so I'm not sure what that does, but it could be that this only sets the environment variable for the current process, and Java is an external process. I would suggest trying to set Java Home globally for your entire system, through Windows settings

Comment: Hm, I tried this tutorial to set JAVA Home https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html, but still doesn't work. I created a new path according to the link, and set a new path to JAVA_HOME jre1.8.0_121. So weird that it didn't work!